# Conditions for the embedding of the space $L^\infty(I, W^{1,2}(U))$ into $L^\infty(I \times U)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $I$ be a compact interval of $\mathbb{R}$ and $U$ be a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

If $f \in L^\infty(I, W^{1,2}(U))$, what (non-trivial) condition ($L^p$-estimate on $f$ or decay-like estimate on the $W^{1,2}$-norm of $f$) is sufficient to obtain that $f \in L^\infty(I \times U)$?

Comment: Can you give some idea of what sort of $L^p$ estimates you have in mind?

Comment: @NateEldredge Honestly I don't have a precise idea.

Comment: Well, doesn't $W^{1,2}(U)$ contains functions like $\ln(x^2+y^2)$, which should be in every $L^p$ but unbounded?  So I don't see how any simple sort of $L^p$ bound is going to help at all.

Comment: @NateEldredge That's true. Maybe some decay-like estimate for some $L^p$ norms or the $H^1$ norm could help?

Comment: @NateEldredge Indeed, $W^{1,2}$ is the limit case for the Sobolev embedding in $L^\infty$ in 2 dimensions. So my guess is that some decay-like condition on the $H^1$ norm should provide the result.

Comment: What is a decay-like condition on a norm?

Comment: Use the sobolev embedding theorem. You can either consider more derivatives or 1 derivative with higher integrability.

Comment: Time plays no role whatsoever here, so your question is equivalent to asking when does $W^{1,2}(U)$ embed into $L^\infty(U)$. This is false of course, see the many comments above.